# Reporte RDLC siempre me imprime una página en blanco al final del reporte

Tags: c#, wpf

borré mi pregunta anterior para repetir la pregunta mejor documentada. Tengo un reporte con hoja tamaño oficio, plano horizontal.

[image: Hoja de diseño]

Se puede ver que las columnas no ocupan todo el ancho de la página, la propiedad **ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace**= true, a cómo recomiendan en varios enlaces de este foro. Los márgenes en la hoja es de 0.5 cm, la cantidad de registro que leo directamente de un datatable, son cinco, para no provocar un salto de página. La propiedad **BrakePage.Disabled** la he probado con false y true, pero siempre ocurre el salto de página. Llevo esto más de una semana sin resolver. Espero realmente resolver esto, está afectando la entrega de un trabajo. Gracias a todos por la ayuda que puedan brindar. Saludos.

Aquí muestro el código del RDLC:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Tablix Name="Tablix5">
        <TablixBody>
          <TablixColumns>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>2.6905cm</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>2.58258cm</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>1.85089cm</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>2.46472cm</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>2.46472cm</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>2.46472cm</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
          </TablixColumns>
          <TablixRows>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.6cm</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="strEmpleadoID">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!strEmpleadoID.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>strEmpleadoID</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="EmpleadoNombres">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!EmpleadoNombres.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>EmpleadoNombres</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Firma">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!Firma.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Firma</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="EmpleadoTelefono">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!EmpleadoTelefono.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>EmpleadoTelefono</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Municipio">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!Municipio.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Municipio</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="RutaID">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!RutaID.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>RutaID</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
          </TablixRows>
        </TablixBody>
        <TablixColumnHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember />
            <TablixMember />
            <TablixMember />
            <TablixMember />
            <TablixMember />
            <TablixMember />
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixColumnHierarchy>
        <TablixRowHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember>
              <Group Name="Detalles" />
            </TablixMember>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixRowHierarchy>
        <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
        <Left>1.62137cm</Left>
        <Height>0.6cm</Height>
        <Width>14.51813cm</Width>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
        </Style>
      </Tablix>
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>0.25in</Height>
    <Style />
  </Body>
  <Width>14.89105in</Width>
  <Page>
    <PageHeader>
      <Height>1.22759cm</Height>
      <PrintOnFirstPage>true</PrintOnFirstPage>
      <PrintOnLastPage>true</PrintOnLastPage>
      <ReportItems>
        <Textbox Name="Textbox32">
          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
          <Paragraphs>
            <Paragraph>
              <TextRuns>
                <TextRun>
                  <Value>Campaña</Value>
                  <Style />
                </TextRun>
              </TextRuns>
              <Style />
            </Paragraph>
          </Paragraphs>
          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox32</rd:DefaultName>
          <Top>0.60537cm</Top>
          <Left>1.62137cm</Left>
          <Height>0.6cm</Height>
          <Width>2.5cm</Width>
          <Style>
            <Border>
              <Style>None</Style>
            </Border>
            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
          </Style>
        </Textbox>
        <Textbox Name="Textbox33">
          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
          <Paragraphs>
            <Paragraph>
              <TextRuns>
                <TextRun>
                  <Value>EID</Value>
                  <Style />
                </TextRun>
              </TextRuns>
              <Style />
            </Paragraph>
          </Paragraphs>
          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox32</rd:DefaultName>
          <Top>0.62018cm</Top>
          <Left>4.1475cm</Left>
          <Height>0.6cm</Height>
          <Width>2.5cm</Width>
          <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
          <Style>
            <Border>
              <Style>None</Style>
            </Border>
            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
          </Style>
        </Textbox>
        <Textbox Name="Textbox34">
          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
          <Paragraphs>
            <Paragraph>
              <TextRuns>
                <TextRun>
                  <Value>Nombres</Value>
                  <Style />
                </TextRun>
              </TextRuns>
              <Style />
            </Paragraph>
          </Paragraphs>
          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox32</rd:DefaultName>
          <Top>0.62759cm</Top>
          <Left>6.67cm</Left>
          <Height>0.6cm</Height>
          <Width>2.5cm</Width>
          <ZIndex>2</ZIndex>
          <Style>
            <Border>
              <Style>None</Style>
            </Border>
            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
          </Style>
        </Textbox>
      </ReportItems>
      <Style>
        <Border>
          <Style>None</Style>
        </Border>
      </Style>
    </PageHeader>
    <PageFooter>
      <Height>0.90911cm</Height>
      <PrintOnFirstPage>true</PrintOnFirstPage>
      <PrintOnLastPage>true</PrintOnLastPage>
      <ReportItems>
        <Textbox Name="ExecutionTime">
          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
          <Paragraphs>
            <Paragraph>
              <TextRuns>
                <TextRun>
                  <Value>=Globals!ExecutionTime</Value>
                  <Style />
                </TextRun>
              </TextRuns>
              <Style />
            </Paragraph>
          </Paragraphs>
          <rd:DefaultName>ExecutionTime</rd:DefaultName>
          <Left>4.0132cm</Left>
          <Height>0.6cm</Height>
          <Width>10.33167cm</Width>
          <Style>
            <Border>
              <Style>None</Style>
            </Border>
            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
          </Style>
        </Textbox>
      </ReportItems>
      <Style>
        <Border>
          <Style>None</Style>
        </Border>
      </Style>
    </PageFooter>
    <PageHeight>21.59cm</PageHeight>
    <PageWidth>35.56cm</PageWidth>
    <LeftMargin>0.5cm</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>0.5cm</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>0.5cm</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>0.5cm</BottomMargin>
    <ColumnSpacing>0.13cm</ColumnSpacing>
    <Style />
  </Page>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="dsSemanaRecorrido">
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>System.Data.DataSet</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>/* Local Connection */</ConnectString>
      </ConnectionProperties>
      <rd:DataSourceID>c1f4357b-166f-43f8-8c8c-53c6772ef8e3</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    
        <rd:SchemaPath>C:\WorkArea\Proyectos.2022\PruebasSistemaDeCompras\Dataset\dsSemanaCompras.xsd</rd:SchemaPath>
        <rd:TableName>dtDiarioRecorrido</rd:TableName>
        <rd:TableAdapterFillMethod />
        <rd:TableAdapterGetDataMethod />
        <rd:TableAdapterName />
      </rd:DataSetInfo>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <ConsumeContainerWhitespace>true</ConsumeContainerWhitespace>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Cm</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>cea81343-7a2e-4b27-b1cf-433bd8e39b6e</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

Comment: Un rdlc no es más que un XML, ábrelo con el block de notas y pega su contenido en tu pregunta

Comment: Específicamente de ese XMl me interesan los nodos ReportSections->ReportSection-> Width y Page

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef, ya agregé el codigo del reporte. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tú tienes que

- Pagina

  - Ancho: 35,56cm
  - Alto: 21,59cm
  - Margen: 0,5cm
- Cabecera (header)

  - Alto : 1,22759cm
- Pie de página (footer)

  - Alto : 0,90911cm

El tema pasa por encontrar los valores para el `cuerpo`

1.- Área útil sin contar los márgenes:

Se debe restar al ancho de la página el margen izquierdo y derecho (2 x 0,5), igualmente al alto el superior y el inferior, quedando

```
Ancho_util = 35,56 - (2x0,5) = 34,56
Alto_util  = 21,59 - (2x0,5) = 20,59
```

2.- Luego al alto debemos restar el header y el footer

*(El ancho no es necesario cambiar nada)*

```
Ancho_cuerpo = Ancho_util
Alto_cuerpo  = alto_util - 1,22759cm 0,90911cm = 18,4533
```

**3.- El problema**

El problema es que los valores del cuerpo deben ser **MENORES** que los presentado, es decir:

```
Ancho_cuerpo < 34,56
Alto_cuerpo  < 18,4533
```

**¿Cuánto menor y porque deben ser menores?**

Ni idea :P !!. Si tuviera que adivinar diría que hay un tema de los bordes, ya que esto mismo pasaba en CSS con IE

Pero en la práctica he notado que debe ser ligeramente menor, entre 0,02cm y 0,015cm, entonces:

```
Ancho_cuerpo = 34,545cm
Alto_cuerpo  = 18,4383cm
```

Comment: Voy a revisar el reporte. Muy agradecido por tu tiempo y ayuda.